# Can't grasp : making a simple singleton in python (for a mongodb manager)

Tags: python, mongodb, class, singleton

I have read the various main examples of singletons but I have trouble making what I want. My main inspiration here is this example :

```
class OnlyOne:
    class __OnlyOne:
        def __init__(self, arg):
            self.val = arg

        def __str__(self):
            return repr(self) + self.val
    instance = None
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if not OnlyOne.instance:
            OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne(arg)
        else:
            OnlyOne.instance.val = arg
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

But I don't need anything like getattr, here is my code so far:

```
class MongoManager:
    class __MongoManager:
        def __init__(self):
            # Initialise client
            self.client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

    __instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not MongoManager.__instance:
            MongoManager.__instance = MongoManager.__MongoManager()
```

All I want is to get the variable **client** when I type `MongoManager.client`, but I get the error `AttributeError: 'MongoManager' object has no attribute 'client'`.
I guess I could try with getattr and check something like `if arg == "client"` but it feels dirty, I'm sure there's a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
class MongoManager:
     __instance = None
     @staticmethod 
     def getInstance():
         if MongoManager.__instance == None:
             MongoManager()
         return MongoManager.__instance
     def __init__(self):
        if MongoManager.__instance != None:
            raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")
        else:
            MongoManager.__instance = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

You can get instance of this class by calling `MongoManager.getInstance()`.

What we are doing here? We have a class variable `__instance` and when object of the class is created, we are initializing it. Now, when we call `getInstance()` this instance which is stored in `__instance` will get passed instead of creating new instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I was looking for a bit more straightforward way, without needing to call a class method. I finally found and posted my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do exactly what I wanted. I didn't completely understand how `__getattr__` worked so a bit more reading was necessary.

```
class MongoManager:
    class __MongoManager:
        def __init__(self):
            # Initialise mongo client
            self.client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

    __instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not MongoManager.__instance:
            MongoManager.__instance = MongoManager.__MongoManager()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.__instance, item)
```

Now whenever I call MongoManager().client, I get the desired client.